# jQuery - accessing an IFrame button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have HTML page that has couple of paragraphs and a reference to an IFrame, the IFrame contains a form, with a couple of text boxes, dropdownlist and a button. When a user clicks the button on the IFrame it send's back a thank you message. The only problem is that the two paragraphs on the HTML page are still showing when the thank you message is displaying. How do I hide the two paragraphs when the button on the IFrame is clicked? (I've rapped two paragraphs around a div)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your `iframe script`,

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
   $('p').hide();
});
```

If the `paragraph elements` are in `parent window` then use `window.parent.document` like,

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
   $('p', window.parent.document).hide();
});
```

Comment: The paragraphs are not inside the iframe, so this code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without markup or javascript I have to guess, but, assuming both the main document and the document displayed in the iframe are in the same domain, that the div in which your paragraphs are contained has an `id` of `pContainer` and your button in the iframe has an id of `formButton` you can do this (as you say nothing, I assume you're not using jQuery):

In the main document script:

```
function hideParagraphs() {
    document.getElementById('pContainer').style.display = 'none';
}
```

In your iframe:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('formButton').addEventListener('click', window.top.hideParagraphs, false);
};
```

Change the `ids` for those that suit your markup.